# Formation of Reflexive Pronouns

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

In English possessive adjectives and reflexive pronouns are

- I - My - Myself
- You - Your - Yourself
- He - His - Himself *
- She - Her - Herself *
- It - Its - Itself *
- They (sing.) - Their - Themself *
- We - Our - Ourselves
- You (pl.) - Your - Yourselves
- They - Their - Themselves *

Except for the starred ones, all reflexive pronouns are formed by combining possessive adjectives and the word "self". But starred ones are formed differently. They use objective pronouns. Why are the formations of these reflexive pronouns different?

Comment: "herself" is not from the possessive ponoun "her"; it is from the OBJECTIVE pronoun "her". And "itself" is not from the possessive pronoun "its"; it is from the OBJECTIVE pronoun "it".

Comment: Have you visited [ell.se] ?

Comment: You've missed out gender-neutral third-person singular 
They - Their - Themself*.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thank you for noticing my mistakes. I edited my question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/themselves-or-themself) says that  themself form is not accepted by everyone. But I have added it.

Comment: The OED says that we used to have *myself* and *meself*, *thyself* and *theeself,* presumably used in different dialects of English. Why did we settle on the selection we have now? Possible either (a) some of these sound better than the alternatives or (b) random chance.

Comment: First and second persons are always different from third in usage and type. First and second person are deictic, while third person is referential. It's common to find some structural difference between the two types in their morphology, too, since they change at different rates for different reasons,

Comment: [Tangentially related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/233606).