# Usage question about plural pronouns

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives

Is there a great deal of difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> 1. **These** looked very different.
> 2. **They** looked very different.

They seem the same to me, but perhaps I am wrong.

*These* is a pronoun. So it can be a subject, can't it?

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), which is probably better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, those sentences differ significantly in having different subjects:

- The first one uses a **personal pronoun** *they* for its subject.
- The second uses the ***proximal* plural demonstrative pronoun** *these* for its subject.

*They* tells you nothing about the location, while the proximal plural demonstrative pronoun *these* contrasts **deictically** with the ***distal* plural demonstrative pronoun** *those*.

Also, as a personal pronoun, *they* has other case inflections like *them, their, theirs, themself, themselves*, while the demonstratives do not alter their forms based on case, only based on number: *this* and *these* are ***proximal* demonstrative pronouns**, while *that* and *those* are ***distal* demonstrative pronouns**.

All four deictics can also function as **demonstrative determiners** (which are a form of definite determiner) as well, while *they* cannot.